# why my nested setTimeout delay not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

When i scroll on my "frame-2" element, i wanted to change the words every 300ms. the word change every 300ms and stop on each word of my array.

The scroll function works. The stop on each word also works but the delay is not of 300ms isn't respected and word change almost instantly. Do you see a mistake that I do not see ?

```
function interval(func, wait, times){
    var interv = function(w, t){
      return function(){
        if(typeof t === "undefined" || t-- > 0){
          setTimeout(interv, w);
          try{
            func.call(null);
          }
          catch(e){
            t = 0;
            throw e.toString();
          }
        }
      };
    }(wait, times);

    setTimeout(interv, wait);
  };

  var words21 = ["communication.", "image.", "concept.", "référencement.", "stratégie.", "contenu.", "social média."];
  var text21 = "repensent votre <span class='surlignement-rouge-text'>communication.</span>";
  var i21;
  var wi21;

  function _getChangedText21() {
    i21 = (i21 + 1);
    if (words21[i21] != undefined) {
      return text21.replace(/communication./, words21[i21]);
    } else {
      return text21.replace(/communication./, words21[wi21]);
      wi21 = (wi21 + 1);
    }
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    text21.replace(/communication./, words21[0]);
    i21 = 0;
    wi21 = 1;
    x = 0;
    var hT20 = $('#frame-2').offset().top,
        hH20 = $('#frame-2').outerHeight(),
        wH20 = $(window).height(),
        wS20 = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (wS20 > (hT20+hH20-wH20)) {
      interval(function _getInterval21() {
        interval(function _changeText21() {
          var txt21 = _getChangedText21();
          document.getElementById("changer2").innerHTML = txt21;
        }, 300, 8);
        selectwords21 = words21[0];
        words21.shift();
        words21.push(selectwords21);
      }, 2000, 6);
      selectwords21 = words21[0];
      words21.shift();
      words21.push(selectwords21);
      selectwords21 = words21[0];
      words21.shift();
      words21.push(selectwords21);
    }
  });
```

Thx a lot,
BadWoo

Edit : here is a codepen exemple : https://codepen.io/BadWoo/pen/MWyQbPB

Comment: what does this line `setTimeout(interv2, w);`  do? it looks like it's supposed to be a recursion of some sort, but the interv2 function is nowhere to be seen, is this a typo?

Comment: What do you mean by "almost" instantly exactly? 300ms is a third of a second, it looks to me fairly "almost" instantly..

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski thanks you, it was a typo error. I edit my question.

Comment: @Kaddath 300ms it's quick but words change even more quickly and when i change this value, like 1000ms the delay doesn't change --'

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - as it stands it's very hard to see what is going on in your question. Your `interval` function works just fine (verified easily by passing a `func` which just logs the current time to the console)

Comment: Thx you @Jamiec i insert a codepen exemple

Comment: @ThéoDumez I'm struggling to see why you would want one `interval` call nested within another when they both do much the same thing.... what effect are you trying to achieve? Also what is the significance of `i21` variable and `wi21` ? Basically, explain what you're trying to do and I assure you the code is _much much_ simpler than youve made it

Comment: @Jamiec I wanted the words to scroll quickly (but stay visible) then stop on the next word and so on.

I called these variables like this to tell them apart because I would like to apply this animation to multiple places on my page. This name has no meaning.

The i21 variable is used to select the word to replace in the table, once all the words in the table have been displayed wi21 is used to display the next word in the list (the one that must remain longer).

Comment: So you're trying to flick all the words quickly and then remain on word 1. Then flick them all quickly and remain on word 2, etc? Is that right? If so I can update my answer

Comment: exactly thx you. I think i will just give up that and trying something more simple

Comment: @ThéoDumez check the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is change the text inside `changer2` for a rotating list of words in place of "communication." you could do this in a few lines of code (See example below).

- No need to keep shifting and pushing words -- just use modulo operator `%`
- No need to have nested calls to a `setTimout` - use `setInterval`

Assuming I've understood correctly what you're trying to achieve here's the working code (adjust the timing as desired):

```js
function changeWords(){

  var words = ["communication.", "image.", "concept.", "référencement.", "stratégie.", "contenu.", "social média."];
  var i = 1;
  setInterval( () => {
    document.querySelector('.surlignement-rouge-text').innerHTML = words[i++ % words.length];
  }, 1000);

}

// You could call this from your scroll handler!
changeWords();
```

```css
.surlignement-rouge-text{
    color: red
}
```

```html
<span id="changer2">repensent votre <span class='surlignement-rouge-text'>communication.</span></span>
```

Having further understood your requirement, it seems the code does need to be a *little* more complex but not much!

```js
var words = ["communication.", "image.", "concept.", "référencement.", "stratégie.", "contenu.", "social média."];

async function changeWords(interval){

  return new Promise( resolve => {
  
    var i = 0;
    var timer = setInterval( () => {
      document.querySelector('.surlignement-rouge-text').innerHTML = words[i++];
      if(i == words.length){
        clearInterval(timer);
        resolve();
      }
    }, interval);
  });
}

async function cycleWords(shortInterval, longInterval, i){
  await changeWords(shortInterval);
  document.querySelector('.surlignement-rouge-text').innerHTML = words[i % words.length];
  setTimeout(() => cycleWords(shortInterval,longInterval, i+1),longInterval);
}

// You could call this from your scroll handler!
cycleWords(300,2000,0);
```

```css
.surlignement-rouge-text{
    color: red
}
```

```html
<span id="changer2">repensent votre <span class='surlignement-rouge-text'>communication.</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `t` will never be `"undefined"`, but it can be `undefined`. And second, instead of calling `setTimeout(interv, wait)` do `setTimeout(interv(), wait)`, because interv returns a function, and that’s what you want to execute.

Comment: Both points are wrong, it's not `t === undefined` but **typeof**, that returns a string. the function for `interv` is ended with `}(wait, times);` so it's an IIFE, it's immediately executed with those parameters, it's a way for the function to remember the local values (because setTimeout fires in the global context)